# CentOS Image Issue on Docker-Compose/Kubernetes Yaml file

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I'm having a dockerfile that runs fine with CentOS as a baseimage and enabled systemd, as suggested on CentOS official docker hub image documentation - https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/.

I'll have to start my container using this following command -

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080  -e "container=docker" --privileged=true -d --security-opt seccomp:unconfined --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro myapplicationImage bash -c "/usr/sbin/init"
```

Till here, everything works like a charm, I can run my image and everything works fine. I'm trying to deploy my image to Azure Container service, so I was trying to create a yaml file that uses this docker image and creates a cluster.

**My Yaml file looks like this.**

```
apiVersion: apps/v2beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp-test
        image: myappregistry.azurecr.io/myapp-test:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        args: ["--allow-privileged=true","bash"]
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add: ["SYS_ADMIN"]
          privileged: true
        command: [ "-c","/usr/sbin/init" ]
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: myapp-secret-test      
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-test
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: myapp-test
```

This doesn't spin-up my image. The above is a kubernetes cluster yaml file. 
I've also tried Docker-Compose.

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp-test:
    build: ./myapp-folder
    environment:
      - container=docker
    volumes:
      - ./sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    privileged: true
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined 
    command: "/usr/sbin/init"
```

Both of these configurations fails to create containers. I'm using same configuration as mentioned in above docker run time command and converted that into yaml. But runtime command works and I can access my application, but yaml files fail. Am I missing anything?

**here is my kubernetes error:**

```
➜  $ kubectl get po --watch                 
NAME                            READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
myapp-test-6957c57f6c-zmbt6   0/1       RunContainerError   4          9m
myapp-test-6957c57f6c-zmbt6   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   4         9m

➜  $ kubectl get svc --watch                                   
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
myapp-test   LoadBalancer   10.0.X.XXX   120.XXX.XX.XXX   8080:30150/TCP   12m
kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.0.0.1      <none>         443/TCP          43m
```

**In case of Docker Compose:**

The container gets kicked in fine, but the service inside my application fails to start. I cannot reach my localhost:8080, but container keeps running.

I'm thinking if it has something to do with my systemd enabled container while accessing it on compose or cluster?

Thanks!

Comment: whats the kubernetes error?

Comment: updated with error.

Comment: did you create docker secret?

Comment: not on my compose, but created imagePullSecrets:- name: myapp-secret-test on kubernester cluster. Do I need created docker secret on compose as well?

Comment: well, if you did that (and looking at your pod status) something is wrong with your container, so it doesnt really start, there are a bunch of ways to troubleshoot that

Comment: yeah exactly, I feel my container isn't getting enabled with systemd. So that my services inside container can start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to add some additional configuration into my centOS image to enable systemd.

```
# named (dns server) service
RUN yum install -y bind bind-utils
RUN systemctl enable named.service 

# webserver service
RUN yum install -y nginx
RUN systemctl enable nginx.service

#Without this, init won't start the enabled services and exec'ing and starting
them reports "Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted".
VOLUME /run /tmp
```

Now my docker container is up and running.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

According to [the fine manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod), if you provide `command:` it supersedes `ENTRYPOINT`, and `args:` supersedes `CMD`, meaning your final "command" that image runs is:

```
-c /usr/sbin/init --allow-privileged=true bash
```

which looks very suspicious with the leading `-c`, especially since your `docker-compose.yml` only contains `/usr/sbin/init`.